# Jquery to add line break <br/> after one or two matched words

Tags: jquery, html

I am looking for a way to insert a `<br />` tag after first or sometimes second word in a `<div>` using jQuery.

For example, given this:

```html
<div class="title">Brand Name Shampoo & conditioner</div>
```

I would like it to become this:

```html
Brand Name<br />
Shampoo & conditioner
```

Basically, I have few, say 10 brand names and ideally I would like the code to match these names with the title and then break the line.

Edit: Adding more examples

```html
<div class="title">Dark Red product name</div>
<div class="title">Blue product name</div>
<div class="title">Pure Orange product name</div>
<div class="title">Crystal White product name</div>
<div class="title">Green product name</div>
```

Comment: you need to read the advice about [marking up code in your question and answer postings](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). If you don't markup the code correctly, the HTML tags vanish (because they don't belong in non-code portions of text). I've edited your question so that it displays correctly, but you can avoid your questions being downvoted in future by marking up your text and your code appropriately from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use classes and not IDs to match the titles as you cannot have duplicate ids in a page:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/w6q7a6L4/

```
$('.title').html(function(){
    return $(this).html().replace('Brand Name','Brand Name<br/>');
});
```

In this instance it uses the ability of jQuery's `html()` to take a function. That function is called for each matching item and each time `this` will be one of the elements. This takes the html() string (which is the innerHTML property of the element), does some string matching and inserts a `<br/>` as required *by your rules*).

For multiples one option is to simply chain the replaces:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/w6q7a6L4/1/

```
$('.title').html(function(){
    return $(this).html().replace('Brand Name','Brand Name<br/>')
        .replace('Another brand', 'Another brand<br/>')
        .replace('Acme', 'Acme<br/>')
        .replace('Brand x', 'Brand x<br/>');
});
```

If you want to data-drive it from an array of brand names:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/w6q7a6L4/3/

```
var brands = ['Brand Name', 'Another brand', 'Acme', 'Brand x'];

$('.title').html(function () {
    var html = $(this).html();
    brands.forEach(function (brand) {
        html = html.replace(brand, brand + '<br/>');
    });
    return html;
});
```

Comment: Thanks TrueBlueAussie, Yes, I have about 10 brand names, does that mean I have to use 10 different statements? Can this be somehow simplified?

Comment: Ok, I got the idea, that's one of the solutions, any other options?

Comment: @Radi: Use the data-driven third example and put you brand names in the array.